# Periodically the retrieved user from the spring security context is empty

Tags: java, spring

I have spring web mvc project with Spring Security 4.1.0.RELEASE

In spring controller i try fetch the user from the context

```
@RestController
public class Test {
 @RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<Void> test() {
   ContextUser user = (ContextUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
 }
}
```

user is an instance with id = 0, login = null .... It is empty instance.
org.springframework.security.core.Authentication isAuthenticated = true, list of Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> are correct This behaviour is occurred periodically. It is not every time for  this request. I catch this issue only for that request

My configurations

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.test.app"},
        excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern={"com.test.app.web.*"}))
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    //My beans
}
```

```
@Component
public class  TestUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private TestUserService service;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = service.findByLogin(userName);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error");
        }
        
        return new ContextUser(user);
    }
}
```

```
public class ContextUser extends User implements UserDetails {
//...
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAsync
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private TestAuthenticationEntryPoint testAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private TestSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler testSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private TestSimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler testSimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private TestUserDetailsService  testUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder registry) throws MyException {
        registry.userDetailsService(testUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new TestEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(testAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession().maximumSessions(-1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).and()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").access("hasAuthority('TEST')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(testSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(testSimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .headers().cacheControl().disable().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**"); 
    }
}
```

Are any ideas why this behaviour is happened?

Comment: For starters your `TestUserDetailsService` is flawed as it should throw an exception if the user cannot be found.

Comment: Sorry In my real code this check is present. I omitted it by chance